# Calling a Batch Class from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, batch, callout

How can I call this Batch Class from Lightning component?

```
 global class BatchSync implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,   Database.AllowsCallouts {


 public String query = 'Select ID, Name from Account';
 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
 }

     global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> records) {         
        String endpoint;        

        for ( integer i = 0; i< records.size(); i++ ){
         try {                  
          HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
          Http http = new Http();
          // Set values to Params

          endpoint = 'Your endpoint';

          req.setHeader('Authorization', header);
          req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
          req.setMethod('POST');
          req.setBody('Information you wanna send');
          req.setCompressed(true); // This is imp according to SF, but please check if
                                 // the webservice accepts the info. Mine did not :P
                                 // Had to set it to false

          if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {      
            res = http.send(req);
            String sJson = res.getBody();
            System.debug('Str:' + res.getBody());
          }             
          // now do what u want to with response.               
          }
          catch (Exception e) {         
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'LN:' + e.getLineNumber() );           
          }
       }
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute batch directly from Lightning component. For this, you need to use a @AuraEnabled method, from that method you can execute the batch.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Account getAccount(Id accountId) {
    // do some preprocessing.
    // execute the batch here
    Id jobId = Database.executeBatch(new BatchSync()); // optional batch size can be provides as well.
}
```

You can also monitor the batch status querying `AsyncApexJob`

[Aura Enabled Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm)

[Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

[AsyncApexJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm)

Comment: Do we need `(cacheable=true)` ? My theory is cacheable is for retriveing data and it does not allow dml

Comment: It seems to me you really don't want this cacheable - you want to ensure that each invocation of the method is actually made against the serve.

Comment: Yes, we don't need it, It was added by mistake. Thanks for the correction